# Break slides in powerdot

Tags: beamer, powerdot

Is there a way to replicate the `\framebreak` functionality of `beamer` in `powerdot`? I really like `powerdot` templates while I also wish to have to convenience of `\framebreak`.

Answer (score 1):

I figure out a trick: to use `\onslide*` feature of `powerdot`. To simulate the feature, put the following in the preamble

```latex
\newcount\slidenum
\slidenum=2
\newcommand{\framebreak}[1]{\onslide*{\slidenum}{#1} \advance\slidenum by 1}
```

Then to write a long slide

```latex
\begin{slide}[]{A fairly long slide}
\onslide*{1}{
First slide
}
\framebreak{
Second slide
}
\framebreak{
Third slide
}
\end{slide}
```

Here is sample output:
[image: Simulating framebreak in powerdot]